# Aren't we duplicating when we pass a redux store to prop and setting that prop to react state again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

This is most common thing every REACT developer does.... We use redux store to maintain the application model if we want to use the store information we have to create a property object using subscription (connect() method) where mapStateToProps creates a cloned read-only version of stored object to reacts PROP. This haven't ended here since the accessible property is read-only we went on to create another instance to react state(to make it writable) of the same object using setState() which is yet another  cloned version of the same object. We end up creating mutiple versions of same object and the weird thing is that we can go on mutate any of these three object without the other knowing it which can be a real havoc..... Is there any way we can prevent this ? ... If so it sure helps the performance and prevents mischief from that cloned objects .

Comment: Well... you shouldn't be turning the props into state. You should be dispatching actions from your react elements with mapDispatchToProps that will update the store and then those changes will propagate back down as props.

Comment: As mentioned above isnt the generated prop read-only i can dispatch every time i want to change the object which is costlier than creating a state.... Even if i do so haven't i end creating mutiple reducer actions if want to change that props internal object ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time with your phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

In react props and state are not supposed to be mixed up. It wont cause any issues in mixing up if its managed properly but there is not use in cloning props to state if we can use the same props value while rendering. So yes it is unnecessary to copy props to state since the changes in both triggers re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

setState method is used to change local state while redux (using actions and reducers) is used to change global state. Usually, there is a situation, as you said, to store both of them so we keep both states in sync. But both do not point to the same object and local state created is not writable. It is non-mutable as well.

As far as redux state (global) is considered, they are changed only using actions and reducers. Mutating any of the states, directly is an anti-pattern to react. The redux state should only be read and not mutated. The local state as well should not be mutated directly. It should be changed using setState method only

Now for your question, if redux state is passed as prop then changes in redux state would automatically re-render the component. But devs usually make a clone (different object) of the redux state to local state, since re-rendering is fast for local state, but changes made to local state are not replicated to redux state automatically.

Comment: `But devs usually make a clone (different object) of the redux state to local state, since re-rendering is fast for local state`. Thats totally wrong and setting state again after a prop change will intiate another round of rerendering which is unnecessary. If you want to change your dom when the prop changes, you should use props itself as data for dom.

Comment: It will not re-render, if I set local state in a lifecycle method like componentWillReceiveProps. The re-rendering in that case would be only once. Just for information react's latest update has added a lifecycle method getderivedstatefromprops which simplifies the process I am talking about